How can we get Sitecore field type with GraphQL Query
I'm working with Next.js and Headless Sitecore 10.3, and I'd like to customize the default GraphQL response from Sitecore.
Specifically, when retrieving field values, I want to include the field type in the response as well.
While I know this customization is possible using a custom content resolver, I'm wondering if it can be achieved directly through a GraphQL query.
Is there a way to modify the query to include this additional information?
query GraphqlQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasourceItem : item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      title {
        value
        //here I want Sitecore Template field type.
      }
      subtitle {
        value
      }
      description {
       value
      }
    }
  }
}


Yes, you can accomplished this using a GQL Query. By including the definition {type}  in your query or You can use __typename to get the type of the field on the desired page, you can retrieve the Sitecore template field type in the GQL Query response.
You can do it with multiple ways.
First Approach: By including the definition {type}  in your query
You can achieve this by modifying your query as follows:
query GraphqlQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasourceItem : item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      title {
        value
        definition {type}
      }
      subtitle {
        value
        definition {type}
      }
      description {
        value 
       definition {type}
      }
    }
  }
}

Adding reference here.

Second Approach: By including the __typename  in your query
You can achieve this by modifying your query as follows:
query ContentQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on About {
      title {
        value
         __typename
      }
      description {
        value
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}

OutPut
{
  "data": {
    "datasource": {
      "id": "1CFDC53BCF784A4CA93C333439067205",
      "name": "About",
      "title": {
        "value": "Hello",
        "__typename": "TextField"
      },
      "description": {
        "value": "Sharma",
        "__typename": "RichTextField"
      }
    }
  }
}

Hope this help!!

Thanks this one worked for me

You can use both __typename or definition {type} to get the type of the field on the desired page.
Here is the sample query.
query {
  item(path: "/sitecore/content/Home/Page 1", language: "en") {
    id
    name
    ... on Page{
      title{
        value
        __typename
        definition {
          type
         }
      }
      content{
        value
         __typename
        definition {
          type
         }
      }
    }
  }
}

And this is what you get.
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "id": "807F14E77F494DB19579DE42E7653F46",
      "name": "Page 1",
      "title": {
        "value": "Page 1",
        "__typename": "TextField",
        "definition": {
          "type": "Single-Line Text"
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "value": "",
        "__typename": "RichTextField",
        "definition": {
          "type": "Rich Text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

So if your requirement is to only include field type then there is no customization needed.
Hope this helps.

You can use the __typename meta-field to get the name of the type associated with a particular field or object. However, __typename only returns the type name of the object itself, not detailed metadata about specific field types within that object.
you can use __typename in a query like this:
query GraphqlQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasourceItem : item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    id
    name
    __typename
    ... on ContentTemplate {
      title {
        value
        __typename
      }
      subtitle {
        value
      }
      description {
        value
      }
    }
  }
}

Hope you find this helpful!

You can use __typename to get the details of the type of the field in GraphQL.
query($datasource1: String!, $language:String! ){
  datasource1: item(path:$datasource1, language:$language){
    id
    name
    ... on Page{
      pageTitle: title{
        value
        type: __typename
      }
      pageContent: content{
        value
        type: __typename
      }
    }
  }
}

Below is the output from GraphQL that contains the details on the type of the field.

Another way to get the same is using definition property on the GraphQL field.
query($datasource1: String!, $language:String! ){
  datasource1: item(path:$datasource1, language:$language){
    id
    name
    ... on Page{
      pageTitle: title{
        value
        definition{
          type
        }
      }
      pageContent: content{
        value
        definition{
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Hope this helps!!!

Hello @ckhnna I have checked that this is giving me different results

@Vaishali Can you please attach the shapshot for the different result you are getting at your end.

Also can you try using the other way specified above..Let me know in case that helps!!!

this is you copied from another answer

@Vaishali There are 2 ways to fetch the same. You can use any of them and both of them should give the details on the type of the field.

yes but your first answer was not worked for me this is giving me TextField for Richtext aswell

@Vaishali You can check the snapshot above.Its giving as expected result for rich text field as well..
